# How to cache big data in memory (efficiently) in complex variables across executions of Python scripts?

Tags: python, tensorflow, caching, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to call (from Java Spring beans) Python Pytorch scripts that contains trained neural networks for the use: my Pytorch neural networks are neural functions that accepts state, encodes it and returns the action, decodes all this is according to learned/trained policy.

So - each time when I am trying to invoke Python script I should construc torch.nn, load weights and biases from some external store (DB, file) and then execute this nn to get single answer, pretty expensive operation.

**How can I keep torch.nn instance (with loaded weights and biases) in memory and make it available immediately for each execution of Python script?**

Memcached is not the solution, because it can keep string or binary values only and it is quite expensive to serialized and deserialize torch.nn instance. One suggestion was Tensorflow Serving, I am currently researching it, so - I don't yet know whether this is the answer.

It is quite possible that Tensorflow has some caching technologies which I can use for the Pytroch as well?

Comment: It's now possible to use the C++ API of PyTorch from Java with the JavaCPP Presets for PyTorch, so you may not need to use Python at all anyway: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/pytorch

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your use case correctly, what you need is a model server that keeps the model loaded and ideally also handles any exceptions from incorrect data.

One rather straightforward way to transform your inference script into a tensorflow-serving-like callable service is the python library [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). Another way seems to be a new tool called [torchserve](https://pytorch.org/serve/).